# UITableView application crash on cellForRow delegate method call

Tags: ios, swift

I have **UITableView** in many **UIViewControllers**. This view controllers load some data from api and place them in `self.data` property. Then Table Views display this data. But accesing `self.data` with **IndexPath** in methods like `cellForRow:` many times seems to cause application crash.

The problem is code like this:

```
let item = data[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
```

I have this view controllers refreshed by socket events. 
I think it can happen simultaneously with scrolling or somehow in the way that loading new data and reloading table view numberOfRows and cellForRow aren't called sequentially but in the same time.

I am trying to use optionals and something like this `data[safe: indexPath.section]?[safe: indexPath.row]` but it adds many boilerplate checking whether we have data or not, and I haven't seen many such usages in tutorials, code examples, etc.

Is there safe way of accessing this arrays just by index and be sure that there will be correct number of elements and crash won't occure?

**UPDATE:**

Now I am using this to solve this problem but it seems odd as in most tutorials I haven't seen that any one is making type check

```
guard let model = data[safe: indexPath.section]?[safe: indexPath.row] else { return 0.1 }

guard let model = data[safe: indexPath.section]?[safe: indexPath.row] else { return UITableViewCell() }
```

Comment: can you add more specific information like code snippet or crash log?

Comment: what crash says? did you try to debug that?

Answer (score 0):

I'll prefer to use if let to check if its have data or not also you can assign a default value to the model properties or use swiftyJSON for the data to avoid the crash

```
if let section = data[indexPath.section]{
    if let data = section[indexPath.row]{
       item = data
     }
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't crash? data[indexPath.section] ? I think it by default doesn't return optional. I am using extension subscript "safe" like this data[safe: indexPath.section]